# How long does it take a for loop to get started?

Tags: c++, performance, for-loop

I am writing a code in C++ where I have the choice between running 1 for loop with 4 addition operations, or running 4 separate for loops, each with 1 addition operation. (as a side note, I was thinking about this because 4-loops-1-addition would mean I allocate 1/4 of the memory in a program I'm writing)

Instinctively I expect 1-loop-4-additions to be faster, and I did a quick benchmark test that demonstrated this. 1-loop-4-additions took somewhere around half the time of 4-loops-1-addition

My question: What processes are happening to make this difference?

Below is the code I used for my test - I'm a mathematician not a programmer, so there is every chance I'm doing something stupid. I'm using a 2D array because that's what I'm coding.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int Nx=100;
    int Ny=Nx;
    double holder=0;

    double test[Nx][Ny];
    double test1[Nx][Ny];
    double test2[Nx][Ny];
    double test3[Nx][Ny];
    double test4[Nx][Ny];

    for(int i=0;i<Nx;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<Nx;j++){
            test[i][j]=1;
            test1[i][j]=1;
            test2[i][j]=1;
            test3[i][j]=1;
            test4[i][j]=1;
        }
    }
    clock_t begin= clock();
    for(int i=0;i<Nx;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<Ny;j++){
            holder=holder + test[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<Nx;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<Ny;j++){
            holder=holder + test[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<Nx;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<Ny;j++){
            holder=holder + test[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<Nx;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<Ny;j++){
            holder=holder + test[i][j];
        }
    }
    clock_t end = clock();
    double elapsed = (double) (end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout<<"Time to run 1 addition in 4 for loops="<<elapsed<<endl;

    begin= clock();
    for(int i=0;i<Nx;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<Ny;j++){
            holder=holder + test1[i][j]+ test2[i][j]+ test3[i][j]+ test4[i][j];
        }
    }
    end = clock();
    elapsed = (double) (end-begin)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    cout<<"Time to run 4 additions in 1 for loop="<<elapsed<<endl;
}
```

Comment: "_I am writing a code in C_" -- But I see C++ code.

Comment: For 100 iterations you will not see any difference at all.

Comment: The most obvious difference is the number of comparisons. Consider how many times `j < Ny` runs total in each case.

Comment: Hmm, are you profiling optimized code?  Every C compiler knows how to unroll loops, unrolling by hand is never necessary.  And every C compiler can generate an assembly listing, have a look-see.

Comment: @e4c5 it's 100x100 iterations - I had to limit it to that number when I ran it on the computer I'm on to a avoid seg fault
@HansPassant as I said, I'm not a programmer, but I did have the `-o` flag when I compiled it with clang++

Comment: @Phill: `-o` (lower-case) specifies the output file. `-O` (upper-case) is the optimization level. `-O` has multiple settings (-O0, -O1, -O2, -O3, -Ofast, -Os, -Oz, -O, -O4) check your compiler manual.

Answer (score 0):

With the first option you are performing  4*(Nx*Ny) operations and with the second one you are performing Nx*Ny operations thus it's normal for the second loop to finish faster for larger Nx,Ny

Comment: If you talk about just *operations*, both the methods perform the same number of *operations*. Talking `asymptotically` is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

Lets take a close look at both the loops and see what things are happening. If you look closely, the number of `addition` operations of the 2D array are same. But, the number of times comparisons like `i<Nx` and `j<Ny` and increment of `i` and `j` are made is different in both the methods. It is 4 times more in the `1st` method.

**This can be one of the reason behind the execution time of both the methods.**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of that. What other things could be going on?